# JPA equal method: Differences between passing ParameterExpression and Object

Tags: java, jpa, parameters

I've written the following piece of code (being `cb` a CriteriaBuilder instance):

```
String someString = "someValue";
Predicate p = cb.equal(
    somePath, 
    cb.parameter(String.class, "someParameter"));
// TODO create query, bind someParameter to someString
```

But the following does the job as well:

```
String someString = "someValue";
Predicate p = cb.equal(
    somePath, 
    someString);
```

Besides type checking, is there any other difference? When the JPA provider parses the query, is performance the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating both queries dynamically using Criteria there should be little difference.  The best would be to use a name query using JPQL, this will avoid any parsing and prepare costs.